# Structure cast is allowed with GCC compiler but not with Visual Studio's

Tags: c, visual-studio, casting, structure

I downloaded the [Keccak Code Package](https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage/archive/master.zip) from their [website](https://keccak.team/software.html) and I'm now trying to implement the Kangaroo Twelve algorithm using the sources they provide in the package.

However, I have a problem that I already experienced when implementing AES-NI key derivation ( that was exactly the same problem ) which is that of the structure cast that is not allowed in Visual Studio as it is in Code Blocks with the GCC Compiler.

So here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    _m256i *stateAsLanes;

    unsigned int i;

    const UINT64 *curData0;
    const UINT64 *curData1;
    const UINT64 *curData2;
    const UINT64 *curData3;

    _m256i lanes0, lanes1, lanes2, lanes3, lanesL01, lanesL23, lanesH01, lanesH23;

    lanes0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const _m256i *)&(curData0[0]));
    lanes1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const _m256i *)&(curData1[0]));
    lanes2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const _m256i *)&(curData2[0]));
    lanes3 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const _m256i *)&(curData3[0]));

    lanesL01= (_m256i )_mm256_permute2f128_ps((__m256)(lanes0), (__m256)(lanes2), 0x20);

    ...
}
```

The error is in the last line:

*cast to type "__m256i" is not allowed*

*cast to type "__m256" is not allowed*

*cast to type "__m256" is not allowed*

I only gave you a piece of the code since it's the exact same "cast to type - Intrinsic type - is not allowed" problem everywhere else in the code.

So here is my final question: How can I get this code to compile under Visual Studio compiler as well as it does with GCC compiler? Is there a way to "allow" those kinds of casts in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem: Visual Studio is a C compiler that's stuck in the last millenium. All it supports is C89. No C99 goodies like `bool`, and as you have discovered, struct casts. MS has indicated no enthusiasm to change this any time soon, if at all.

It may be worth a try to compile it with the VS C++ compiler, but be aware that C and C++ are different languages and there are valid C programs that are valid C++ programs with different behavior. I would not trust such an executable.

My advice is to forget about compiling that software with VS and install a recent gcc that works on Windows (Cygwin, Mingw). There's also clang which is a fine candidate and has gcc-compatible options.

Comment: Arf, ok, I'll go for Mingw but that's not convenient at all... Too bad

Comment: Actually despite being very late to the party, MS has mostly caught up with C99 now (as of VS 2015 I think ?). It’s still a very annoying compiler though.